# exporting text file with utf-8 encoding in ms access

Tags: sql, vba, encoding, utf-8, ms-access-2010

I am exporting text files from 2 queries in ms access 2010. Queries are from different linked ODBC tables (but tables are different only by data, structure and data types are same). I set up export specification to export text file in utf-8 encoding for both files. Now here come the trouble part. When I export the queries and open them in notepad, one query is in utf-8 and second one is in ANSI. I don't know how is this possible when both queires has the same export specification and it is driving me crazy.

This is my VBA code to export queries:

> DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "miniflow", "qry01_CZ_test", "C:\TEST_CZ.txt", no
>      DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "miniflow", "qry01_SK_test", "C:\TEST_SK.txt", no

I also tried to modify it by adding 65001 as coding argument by the results were same.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Does the saved export specification you are using specifically select `Unicode (UTF-8)` encoding, like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jvdua.png)?

Comment: Yes, exactly like this.

Comment: How are you determining that one export is "in utf-8" while the other is "in ANSI"? Are you using a hex editor to inspect the encoding of accented characters like `é` (which is `E9` in "ANSI" and `C3 A9` in UTF-8)?

Comment: I've just open the file in notepad and first file is in UTF-8 and the socond one is in ANSI (like [this](http://imageshack.com/a/img843/9861/un891.jpg)). But if I open them in pspad hex editor then the characters resemble to what you've written - é in ansi is E9 but in utf-8 é is EFBBBFC3A9. Does that help you?

Comment: é in utf-8 is like EFBBBFC3A9 only at the beginning, if I put char somewhere else then it is C3A9 as you wrote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't rely on the File Open dialog in Notepad to tell you whether a text file is encoded as "ANSI" or UTF-8. That is just Notepad's "guess" based on whether the file begins with the bytes `EF BB BF`, which is the UTF-8 Byte Order Mark (BOM).

Many (*most?*) Windows applications will include the UTF-8 BOM at the beginning of a text file that is UTF-8 encoded. Some Unicode purists insist, often quite vigorously, that the BOM is not required for UTF-8 files and should be excluded, but that is the way Windows applications tend to behave.

Unfortunately, Access does not always follow that pattern when it exports files to text. A UTF-8 text file exported from Access may omit the BOM and that can confuse applications like Notepad if they assume that a UTF-8 encoded file will always include the BOM as the first three bytes of the file.

For a more reliable way of determining the encoding of a text file consider using an application like [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to open the file. It will differentiate between the UTF-8 files *with* a BOM (which it designates as "UTF-8") and UTF-8 files *without* a BOM (which it designates as "ANSI as UTF-8")

To illustrate, consider the following Access table

[image: access.png]

When exported to text (CSV) with UTF-8 encoding,

[image: ExportSpec.png]

the File Open dialog in Notepad reports that it is encoded as "ANSI"

[image: notepad.png]

but a hex editor shows that it is in fact encoded as UTF-8 (the character `é` is encoded as `C3 A9`, not simply `E9` as would be the case for true "ANSI" encoding)

[image: hexedit.png]

and Notepad++ recognizes it as "ANSI as UTF-8"

[image: npp.png]

in other words, a UTF-8 encoded file without a BOM.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation! This is my case. When I open file in hex editor, é is encoded as C3 A9. This is great relief. Damn you win notepad :)